# Probability of drawing a sequence of increasing large outliers

Tags: probability

News today (e.g, [NY Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/18/science/earth-highest-temperature-record.html)) that the Earth has set a third successive high temperature record made me wonder if the temperatures were not increasing, what would be the probability of such an outcome.

Here's an attempt at formalizing that question: suppose that global mean temperature is normally distributed $N(\mu, \sigma)$ and $N$ samples have been drawn from this distribution: $T_1, \cdots, T_N$. Let $T_{maxN}$ be the maximum of those first $N$ samples.

What then is the probability that the next three samples drawn are successively greater than the maximum of the first $N$ samples, i.e.,

$$P(T_{N+3} > T_{N+2} > T_{N+1} > T_{maxN})$$

Comment: Your formulation is not correct: you are asking for the probability that given $N+3$ samples of a normal distribution the last $3$ are increasing. What is really happening is that given $N+M+K+L$ samples normally distributed the max of the firs $N$ is less than the max of the following $M$ and so on... This condition has surely an higher probability.

Answer (score 1):

If there have been $n$ items,
with the value of each
randomly chosen
from the same distribution,
the chance of the $n+1$-st being largest
is $\frac1{n+1}$.

Repeating this,
the chance of the
three consecutive records is
$\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$.

Answer (score 1):

That's just like asking:

"if there is a race between $N+3$ identical contestants $1,2,\ldots N+3,$ with equal chance of finishing in any order, what is the probability that the first three finishers are contestants $1,2,3$ in that order."

There are $N!$ different orders satisfying this criterion (from the $N!$ rearrangements of the finishers from 4th place to last) and $(N+3)!$ orderings total, so the probability is $$\frac{N!}{(N+3)!} = \frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)}$$

Comment: Same answer I got with different reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

**Reality check.** Here is a simulation of your version of the question with only $n = 5$ historical observations. (With larger $n,$ chances pretty clearly go down.) 
Without loss of generality, assuming there is no temperature trend,
I took all observations to be standard normal.

My variable $X$ counts the number of the three new
observations that are above the maximum of the five old ones. I got $P(X = 3) \approx 0.018.$ So just that is a rare event (regardless of the *order* of the
three new temperatures.)

My 
random variable $Y$ counts the number of increases in the sequence
$(T_{5:5}, T_6, T_7, T_8),$ where $T_{5:5}$ is the biggest of the historical five
observations. In order for $T_{5:5} < T_6 < T_7 < T_8$ we must have $Y = 3,$
and that *never* happened in a million iterations.

```
m= 10^6; n = 5; x = y = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  t = rnorm(n); t.max = max(t)
  new = rnorm(3)
  x[i] = sum(new > t.max)                # nr new above t.max
  y[i] = sum(diff(c(t.max, new) > 0))  } # 3 means incr from t.max on
mean(x == 3);  mean(y == 3)
## 0.017736  # aprx prob all 3 new exceed max of 5 historical
## 0         # aprx prob max.t < t.6 < t.7 < t.8
```

Certainly, this doesn't mean temperatures aren't trending upward, by some reasonable definition of 'trending upward'. It just means
the particular event NYT chose to report is rare, if temperatures are steady. (Newspapers are partly in the business of reporting
surprising events.) Maybe you need to formulate and investigate some scheme such as the one @N74 suggests.

*Note:* Driving around with a friend earlier today, we noted digits of license plates
of five oncoming cars (part of an extraordinarily stupid game). In our state
most plates have a cluster of three digits: We recorded `873 129 322 573 903`, what are the chances
that will be *exactly* repeated on our next trip?